# How can I get a host name to connect from outside instead of 'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm setting up a Database that will go into my android studio project, the host name i'm getting now is localhost.

I'm not sure if it's the reason why the data I input from the app simulator isn't going into the db

I tried to remote sql server but it's no use, trying to get a real host that can connect from outside

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "u915826651_user", "9811Ryan", "u915826651_fju2");
```

expected to get data that i input from the simulator

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself.

Comment: use your actually accessible machine IP, not `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Not real clear to me what you are asking.  Are you developing at home and now want to connect to a database on a hosted server somewhere ?  Hosting services handle that differently.  Mine requires a ssh signin that routes mysql port to their server through ssh:

```
ssh -f cPanel_username@server_hostname -p21098 -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

If that is the scenario, check with your hosting service.  Another issue (if you are trying to connect to your local host on a dev server on the same network) could be whether you are trying to connect via socket or TCP/IP.  You might have to enable network access on your server and use 127.0.0.1.  I use MAMP, and I think it works that way.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. They seem to have a problem using PHP's MySQLi library.